# Mule poolExhaustedAction

Tags: multithreading, mule, profile

I'm trying to make sure I understand the meaning of the poolExhaustedAction values for a threading profile.  I'm not seeing a lot of examples out there.

Assume I have a thread pool on an HTTP endpoint that has maxThreadsActive set to "16".  I receive 20 inbound requests in a short period (faster than I can process any of them).

If poolExhaustedAction is set to "WAIT" then the last 4 requests will wait for threadWaitTimeout.  Is this correct?

If poolExhaustedAction is set to "RUN" then the last 4 requests will ????...use the thread that carried the request to the endpoint to run the flow????  I'm a bit confused on this one.  Specifically, if set to "RUN", will the service ever reject a request (assuming Mule has threads to deliver messages to it)?

Comment: Please have a look at related SO question and its answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103558/mule-threading-profiles-poolexhaustedaction-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance? Especially [this part](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance#TuningPerformance-DefaultThreadingProfileThedefaultthreadingprofile,usedbycomponentsandbyendpointsfordispatchingandreceivingifnomorespecificconfigurationisgiven)?

Answers to your questions are:

1. Yes.
2. Indeed the thread that received the request will be used to process it in the flow. The service will start rejecting requests when inbound socket connections will time-out because the thread in charge of routing them in Mule is too busy to accept them.

Comment: I did read that.  I found it less than clear on the second point.  Your answer is clearer.  Thanks.