# Mule Threading Profile's poolExhaustedAction - RUN

Tags: multithreading, mule

I have already gone through this

- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Tuning+Performance#TuningPerformance-ThreadingProfileConfigurationReference
- [Mule poolExhaustedAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578908/mule-poolexhaustedaction)

I have some confusion around `RUN` poolExhaustedAction.

If poolExhaustedAction is set to `RUN` and there are no threads available in the pool, will the request receiver thread continue with flow? If so, is this a Synchronous processing?

**EDIT:** Suppose I have a mule flow configuration like:

- Flow processing strategy is asynchronous.
- The thread pool sizes of `Receiver`, `Flow` and `Dispatcher` is 1.
- Finally the `poolExhaustedAction` of `Receiver` and `Dispatcher` is `RUN`.

  With the above mentioned configuration, my question follows like, imagine Flow thread pool is exhausted and a new request from client is received by the (only one) thread from Receiver pool. Will this receiver thread continue the flow processing or wait? If I understood it correctly, the receiver thread doesn't wait, as its `poolExhaustedAction` is set to `RUN`. So isn't this a Synchronous processing form the perspective of receiver thread? Then what is the use of setting `asynchronous` processing strategy?

Now I have changed the above configuration such that `Dispatcher's` `poolExhaustedAction` is set to `WAIT`. Will the above receiver thread wait for dispatcher thread? I don't think so.

Please clarify my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the following link where I have explained the WAIT and RUN poolExhaustedAction values.

[Mule Exhausted Action RUN vs WAIT. Which one to choose and when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365054/mule-exhausted-action-run-vs-wait-which-one-to-choose-and-when/26366521#26366521)

For your question related to RUN.

In case of asynchronous processing streategy, Yes. When the flow threads are exhausted the request receiver thread continues with the processing of the request. But this is not synchronous. Because if there are 4 receiver threads all 4 receiver thread might continue processing of the request. And they all might be running parallely.

**Answer for the Edited OP:**
Because only one thread is executing the processing doesn't mean synchronous. As mentioned earlier Receiver thread only starts after the flow thread pool is exhausted. Means that the flow threads are all busy in processing, in this case the one thread is still processing and cannot take a new request for processing. So the receiver thread started processing. So this is still not synchronous.

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: @user1760178, Thanks for your explanation. I have still confusion, suppose I have configured like this: flow thread pool size is 1 and receiver thread pool size is 1 and processing strategy is asynchronous. Now imagine, flow thread pool is exhausted. Will the receiver thread continue processing the flow, if flow thread poolExhaustedAction is `RUN`? If so, wont the processing look synchronous from the perspective of receiver thread?

Comment: That is not the case. Even though you say only one receiver thread is existing. The receiver thread starts processing only if all the flow threads are still processing. Which means the receiver thread is not the only thread that is in the process of request processing in that flow. And for synchronous there can be onlt on theread processing in the flow at any point of time and it should be the only thread that can process the requests for that flow. Even if the threads are not concurrent there will not be two threads for a synchronous flow.

Comment: Could you please see the EDIT section of the question and provide clarification?